# MVVM how do i update row that doesnt contain viewmodel?

Tags: android, android-intent, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel

I'm learning MVVM.

I have the mainactivity containing recyclerview which has the viewmodel to the room database and an addeditactivity for rows. I also have a rowinfoactivity.

Rowinfoactivity takes an intent and displays all relevant values.

Pressing Button leads to AddEditActivity fires from mainactivity startactivityforresult with intent containing data... then on return updates/add on main activity with viewmodel commands.

My issue is that I want to move the edit button part to Rowinfoactivity, that is... pressing a button there will take you to addeditactivity because it's convenient... so how do i save the changes to the room database when both Rowinfoactivity and AddEditActivity doesnt have a viewmodel?

only mainactivity has a viewmodel...

Answer (score 0):

If you start learning MVVM in 2020, you should consider learning a Single-Activity approach. There you only have one activity, multiple fragments and one (shared) ViewModel for each fragment.

Google for shared ViewModel and you will find a lot.

I suggest to watch this android dev video:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU